# javascript bitwise operation in the condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how bitwise operation works in Javascript especially when used as the condition result.

```
const number = 19

if(number & 1) {
  console.log('one')
}
if(number & 2) {
  console.log('two')
}
if(number & 4) {
  console.log('four')
}
if(number & 8) {
  console.log('eight')
}
if(number & 16) {
  console.log('sixteen')
}
// one two sixteen

if(number & 1 === 1) {
  console.log('one')
}
if(number & 2 === 2) {
  console.log('two')
}
if(number & 4 === 4) {
  console.log('four')
}
if(number & 8 === 8) {
  console.log('eight')
}
if(number & 16 === 16) {
  console.log('sixteen')
}
// one two four eight sixteen
```

The first part of the code produces one two sixteen which I expect it to be.
But the second part of the code produces one two four eight sixteen.
Since number & 4 should be 0, it should not print out 'four' here, the same for 'eight'. What do I misunderstand here?

Comment: [`number & (4 === 4)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) == `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), The precedence value of `===` (**10**) is greater than `&`(**9**). That's why `19 & 4 === 4` is executed as `19 & (4 === 4)` here.

Comment: Do you know the reason why === should have higher precedence than &?

Answer (score 3):

You are facing a problem with [operator precendence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence): `===` has a higher precendence than `&`. `number & 1 === 1` will thus be evaluated as `number & (1 === 1)`.

To solve that you have to add proper grouping:

```
(number & 1) === 1
```

Comment: Do you know the reason why === should have higher precedence than &?